# Different output of recursive functions in C and Python

Tags: python, recursion

I have a `drawPyramid_recursive` function implemented in both C and Python. The logic is the same among them. However, the outputs of them are different. Why is the case? Are there any discrepancies in the **function call stack** for recursion with C and Python?

---

C version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void drawPyramid_recursive(int height, int level)
{
    if (level == 0) // base case
    {
        return;
    }
    
    return drawPyramid_recursive(height, level - 1);

    for (int column = height - level; column >= 1; --column)
    {
        printf(" ");
    }

    for (int column = 1; column <= level; ++column)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("  ");

    for (int column = 1; column <= level; ++column)
    {
        printf("#");
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    int height;
    do
    {
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%i", &height);
    }
    while (height > 8 || height < 1);

    drawPyramid_recursive(height, height);
}
```

Output of C version:

```
Height: 3
  #  #
 ##  ##
###  ###
```

---

Python version:

```
def drawPyramid_recursive(height, level):
    if (level == 0):  # base case
        return

    drawPyramid_recursive(height, level - 1)

    for level in range(1, height + 1):
        for column in range(height - level, 0, -1):
            print(" ", end="")

        for column in range(1, level + 1):
            print("#", end="")

        print("  ", end="")

        for column in range(1, level + 1):
            print("#", end="")

        print()


def main():
    while True:
        height = input("Height: ")
        height = int(height)
        if (height >= 1 and height <= 8):
            break

    drawPyramid_recursive(height, height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output of Python version:

```
Height: 3
  #  #
 ##  ##
###  ###
  #  #
 ##  ##
###  ###
  #  #
 ##  ##
###  ###
```

Comment: Your C code doesn't have the equivalent of the `for level in range ...` loop in your Python

Comment: You also do not return the recursive call in python. Seems weird to me anyway that the C-function continues after that return statement..

Comment: @user2390182, it does not. at least on repl.it I guess their actual C code does not have `return` on that line `return drawPyramid_recursive(height, level - 1);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

First:

> The logic is the same among them.

No. The logic is different. Please have a second look at the line `for level in range(1, height + 1):` in your Python code, which doesn't appear in your C code...

Second:
You should probably get rid of the keyword `return` at the beginning of the line `return drawPyramid_recursive(height, level - 1);` in your C code. Otherwise you won't get any `#` printed... See here: https://godbolt.org/z/TYYvWzqKb

Answer (score 1):

In your Python code, there is this code:

```py
for level in range(1, height + 1):
    for column in range(height - level, 0, -1):
        print(" ", end="")
```

But in your C code, there isn't any equivalent.

Consider adding this in your C code:

```c
for(int level = 1; level <= height; ++level)
{
    for(int column = height - level; column >= 0; --column)
    { 
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

Also, in your C version, you `return drawPyramid_recursive(height, level - 1);` but you didn't return in your Python version: `drawPyramid_recursive(height, level - 1)` You should remove `return` and change your C code to: `drawPyramid_recursive(height, level - 1);`